# Show whether $\sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k!}{k^k}$ and $\sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{(k+1)k}}$ converge.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

title, I'm not sure how to reason about series converging or not (outside of using the calculus tests, but this is real analysis...) and intuition isn't enough for a rigorous proof.

Comment: Hint for second. $k(k+1)\le(k+1)^2$

Comment: @tetori is this valid for all k?

Comment: yes. This inequality is vaild if $k\ge 1$.

Comment: @terribleatmath. Even if the inequality is valid only after some $k>N$ the divergence would be still true

Comment: @boywholived can you explain why this series diverges?

Comment: @terribleatmath. If you can tell where you are facing problem I can help.

Comment: Well, im confused as to how I should be thinking of this in an analysis class. I have a number of tools I already know of to consider this (ratio test, comparison test, etc) but thinking purely definition-wise, I could consider partial sums and look for limits, etc. What do you do?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint for first series** If $k>3$ then
$$
\frac{k!}{k^k} =\frac{k}{k}\cdot \frac{k-1}{k}\cdots \frac{2}{k}\frac{1}{k}\le\> ???
$$
give a appropriate upper bound and use comparison test.

*Possible upper bound* (If you bring your mouse pointer at below then you can see this.)

> $$\frac{k}{k}\cdot\frac{k-1}{k}\cdots\frac{3}{k}\cdot \frac{2}{k}\cdot\frac{1}{k} \le 1\cdot 1\cdots 1\cdot\frac{2}{k}\cdot  \frac{1}{k}$$

Comment: thanks! also, you have a typo in your answer: "approciate" should be "appropriate"

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{(k+1)!}{(k+1)^{k+1}}/\frac{k!}{k^k}=\frac{k!}{(k+1)^{k}} \times \frac{k^k}{k!}=\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^k \to 1/e <1$
The series is convergent by d'Alambert test.

Comment: never heard of the d'Alambert test -- what is it?

Comment: This is what you call ratio test.